# Django database entry created by concatenation of two fields

Tags: python, django

I have the following Django model

```
class Labels(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    live = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    unique_key = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s / %s' % (self.user, self.label)
```

I would like `unique_key` to be automatically populated with a concatenation of `md5(user + label)`

e.g.

`user` = 'James'

`label` = 'KDJ'

`concat = user + label
unique_key = print(hashlib.md5(concat.encode()).hexdigest())`

Output

`1935636b374a17f87636460e4307f736`

Answer (score 2):

You can override save method for this:

```
class Labels(models.Model):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        concat = self.user + self.label
        self.unique_key = hashlib.md5(concat.encode()).hexdigest()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```