# Django Model - CharField as concatenation of other fields

Tags: django, django-models

I'm learning Django and looking for a best practice:

Imagine I have a model for a mobile phone device:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    vendor = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    line = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Let's say I create an object like this:

```
Device.objects.create(vendor = "Apple",
    line = "iPhone",
    model = "SE"
)
```

or without "line":

```
Device.objects.create(vendor = "Xiaomi",
model = "Mi 6"
)
```

Then I'd like to track sales in my shop for every device, so I create a model for a "Deal" (I track only the deal date and the device sold, device as a ForeignKey):

```
class Deal(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    deal_date = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
```

Question:
What is the best way to create a "Deal" object, if I want to query "Device" by its full, concatenated name, e.g. "Apple iPhone SE" or "Xiaomi Mi 6"? 
I've found something similar in [Django database entry created by concatenation of two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49548802/django-database-entry-created-by-concatenation-of-two-fields) , however not sure if it's the right path in my case.

My best guess is something like this (where "name" is a concatenated field):

```
de = Device.objects.get(name = "Apple iPhone SE")
Deal.objects.create(device = de,
deal_date = datetime(2018, 4, 26, 15, 28)
)
```

What is the correct way to do this task? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: you can try to read this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520445/overriding-get-method-in-models?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa . You should override `get()` method of model.Manager. Or, better, write your own `get_full_name()` method. If that doesn't help - i try to code tomorrow :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, still I have some troubles understanding it :( I believe the function should look like this, however I still don't understand how to get an object with it:     `def get_full_name(self):
        if line:
            fullname = vendor + " " + line + " " + model
        else:
            fullname = vendor + " " + model
        return fullname`

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you var `name` contains your text search criteria, and usign your data models, you could use `annotation` to create a field to each object returned by your query set, and then filter using this field

You could try some as follow (it is not tested)

```
import datetime

from django.db.models import F
from your.app.models import Deal, Device


# supposing is in your view, but like sounds as a model method

def my_view(request, *args, **kwargs)
    name = request.POST.get('name')
    device_qs = Decive.objects.all().annotate(text_concatenated='{} {} {}'.format(F('vendor'), F('line'), F('model'))).filter(text_concatenated=name)

    try:
        device = device_qs.get()
    except Device.DoesNotExist:
        # to manage the scenario when doesn't exist any match
        # here you manage this situation
        pass
    except Device.MultipleObjectsReturned:
        # to manage the scenario when various devices have the same 'text concatenated', i dont know, maybe data model should be improved
        # here you manage this situation
        device = device_qs.first()

    deal = Deal.objects.create(device=device, deal_date=datetime.datetime.now())

    # build your response and return it
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your advice guys, searching a little bit more I've found an answer appropriate in my case:
what I did is I tweaked `save()` method, which now populates a field automatically as a concatenation of 3 other fields.
`@property`was usefull in this case too